# Many-to-one mapping with multiple columns in Excel using Python

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I have a mapping table that looks like the below in Excel, where columns B-L each contain names of column headers from two separate datasets which needs to be mapped to the new column headers in column A in a new, concatenated dataset formed of the two separate datasets.

```
A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I    J    K    L       
Ant  Car            Bin   
Bat  Bat            Gat  Rat  Mat  Sat  Pat  Fat  Cat  Hat
```

In the example above, `Bat` from Dataset 1 (Col B) needs to map to `Bat` in the new, concatenated dataset (Col A) and the column headers in columns E-L which are from Dataset 2 need to all map to `Bat` (Col A) such that the data in the rows below these columns in Dataset 2 is added together, i.e.

```
Bat = Gat + Rat + Mat + Sat + Pat + Fat + Cat + Hat
```

The added complexity in the above arises where a user could choose to add a column from Dataset 1 or Dataset 2 into Col C-D or Col F-L, respectively, in the future - and would expect the Python code to be able to recognise this and concatenate the data in the additive form above.

I am aware that `groupby` functionality in `pandas` can be used to group `Gat, Mat, Sat etc` additively, but am stuck with how to deal with allowing for user changes to the mapping table.

I have considered iteratively checking each cell for values using a `for` loop to check where the user has input column headers under Col C-D and Col F-L, and ignoring `NaN` cells, but how do I then proceed to deal with the mapping?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a secondary mapping, which is a transpose of the original and only includes a the subset of the columns with many-to-one mappings (i.e. Col E-L).

Filter this mapping for rows with more than one entry i.e.

```
min_nas = 1
map_sub = map_sub.loc[:, (map_sub.notnull().sum(axis=0) > min_nas)]
```

Transpose back to normal, use `pd.melt()`, and append back to the original mapping keeping only Col A, B and E. Then proceed with mapping on a one-for-one basis as follows:

```
map_sub = map_sub.T
map_sub.reset_index(level='[insert name of Col A here]', inplace=True)
keys = [c for c in map_sub if c.startswith('[insert Col E-L name prefix here]')]
map_sub = pd.melt(map_sub, id_vars='[insert name of Col A here]', value_vars=keys, value_name='[insert name of Col E here]')
```

Clean up:

```
map_sub = map_sub.dropna() # drop all rows and columns with nan
del map_sub['variable'] # remove variable column
```

Append to original mapping:

```
newmapping = mapping.append(map_sub, sort=False, ignore_index=True)
newmapping = newmapping[['[insert name of Col A here]','[insert name of Col B here]', '[insert name of Col E here]']] # keep just 3 relevant columns for one-to-one mapping.
```

Proceed to map on one-for-one basis.